# Does changing a variable's type cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks

I love that JavaScript is loosely typed.

To be honest though, I rarely think about memory management when using it.

When a variable is created, even in JS, a certain amount of memory is allocated for that variable. However, variables in JavaScript are mutable. What happens when a variable is changed from one type to another?

For example:

```
var a = "hello world"; //~22 bytes
a = 10;                //now 'a' is only 8 bytes
```

Do the remaining 14 bytes get garbage collected? Or does this cause a memory leak?

Comment: Strange question. If simple code like this caused a memory leak then how could you use most websites without your computer dying?

Comment: No. Variables in essentially all such languages are implemented as references to typed memory buffers in the heap. When the value is changed, the variable is simply changed to reference another object in the heap. If the variable was the last reference to the object, whatever reference counting/garbage collecting mechanism is used should eventually kick in and free that heap memory.

Comment: The only exception to the above is that, in some language runtimes, simple types with fixed sizes like booleans, integers, and floats are stored directly "in" the variable; i.e. the field that would normally contain the pointer to the heap contains the data and is somehow marked as such.

Comment: @Linuxios: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: @boundry: What are your referring to? I've already upvoted your answer; I just thought I'd add a little about the mechanisms.

Comment: @Linuxios: Your comments should have been an answer :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition : Oh! Thanks, I'll add one. Just goes to show that even programmers aren't that good at understanding symbols :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Variables in essentially all such languages are implemented as references to typed memory buffers in the heap. When the value is changed, the variable is simply changed to reference another object in the heap. If the variable was the last reference to the object, whatever reference counting/garbage collecting mechanism is used should eventually kick in and free that heap memory.

The only exception to the above is that, in some language runtimes, simple types with fixed sizes like booleans, integers, and floats are stored directly "in" the variable; i.e. the field that would normally contain the pointer to the heap contains the data and is somehow marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no memory leaks built into the JavaScript language (which doesn't emplace any mandates on memory allocation at all).

If an implementation has a memory leak on the shown code, it is (very) buggy.

Most likely some object in the underlying engine is entirely replaced with a new one, and a logical "reference" repointed to the replacement object.

Comment: There actually are memory leaks in JavaScript. That said, I think your answer is likely correct about the variable being replaced and created elsewhere. Do you happen to have a reference for that?

Comment: No, there are not memory leaks in JavaScript. Again, the language doesn't even have the concept of memory allocation. And a leaky engine is (obviously) buggy. I guess you're referring to what happens when you create a circular reference; that's a bug in your program, not in the language!

Comment: And no I don't have a reference; unpicking how compilers and JavaScript engines work is well beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer. Hence "most likely". Suffice it to say, assigning to a variable in JavaScript does not leak memory, and I don't know why you think it would.

Comment: I guess maybe we are arguing the same thing. While the language itself has a garbage collector, it is still possible for programs written in JavaScript to have memory leaks. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Comment: @itcropper: Again, the language does not have a garbage collector, any more than English has a spell checker. Of course it is still possible to misspell things if you're not very good at English. :)

Comment: I'm starting to question your qualifications to answer this question. JavaScript does indeed have a garbage collector. "JavaScript values are allocated when things (objects, strings, etc.) are created and "automatically" freed when they are not used anymore. The process is called garbage collection." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: @itcropper: There is no need to be so rude just because you do not understand what you are being told. Read the ECMAScript standard. Garbage collection isn't even mentioned. This is a concept created by _implementations_, as I've already said, sloppy wording on Mozilla's website notwithstanding.